# Does "whatever" need a verb?

Tags: grammar

[image]

> We will do everything we can to help anybody, ____ his background, to
>   go as far as his talents will take him.

The answer is supposed to be "whatever". But someone argues "whatever" must have a verb behind.

> ... whatever his background is ...

And I find this, said by Britain PM Teresa May,

> We will do everything we can to help anybody，**whatever** your
>   background，to go as far as your talents will take you.

Comment: *whatever his background is* is reduced here to a verbless construction - *whatever his background*. Both the finite and non-finite construction are correct.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We will do everything we can to help anybody, *whatever his background (is)*, to go as far as his talents will take him.

This sentence is correct, regardless of whether the bracketed verb is included or omitted. But they are different constructions. With *is* included, it is finite (Open Interrogative clause). And without *is* it is non-finite (Verbless clause).

The function of the open Interrogative clause - *whatever his background is* - is Ungoverned Exhaustive Conditional Adjunct. This type of adjunct is semantically non-restrictive.

**INTERPRETATION OF MEANING:**

Say, **X** is his background. **X** can have any value *like* Doctor, engineer, homeless, refugee, rich, poor etc.

> We will do everything we can to help anybody, *whose background is any value of **X***, to go as far as his talents will take him.

In other words, it means *we will help anybody, irrespective of his background, to go as far as his talents will take him*.

**REDUCTION FROM FINITE TO NON-FINITE:**

Conditional interrogatives can be commonly reduced to a participial or verbless construction. In here *whatever his background is* is reduced to a verbless construction *whatever his background*.

**REFERENCE:**
The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language page no. 990, 987, 1068, 1072 (footnote), 1001, 761

Answer (score -1):

I love questions like this, because the answer is simple: No, it doesn't, this is perfectly natural usage as it is. (SO don't allow one word answers!)

Adding `is` would not be grammatically wrong, but is a minor usage, as your quote shows.